# How to add a comma separated values in once cell in CSV with java

Tags: java, excel, csv, export-to-csv

i would like to add the following value `1,345,000.99` as one value in CSV file using java.

when i opened the `CSV` file using excel then the values are shown into different colums since CSV writing considers each comma as new cell value and writes into new column.

could someone help me as how to have `1,345,000.99` in a single cell.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the whole text in double quotes, so the commas are not interpreted as column separators.